# Searching for multiple paths using same code for xpathSApply

Tags: html, r, xpath, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract the table which contain an Arabic poem. You can check the poem in [here](http://www.adab.com/modules.php?name=Sh3er&doWhat=shqas&qid=65546&r=&rc=1)

I tried to parse the table...

```
URL <- "http://www.adab.com/modules.php?name=Sh3er&doWhat=shqas&qid=65546&r=&rc=1"
Data <- htmlTreeParse(URL, useInternalNodes = TRUE,encoding = "Windows-1256")
Poem <- xpathSApply(Data,"//p[@class='poem']",xmlValue)
Poem1 <- xpathSApply(Data,"//font[@class='poem']",xmlValue)
Encoding(Poem) <- "UTF-8"
Encoding(Poem1) <- "UTF-8"
```

But that's not good because i changed the order which poem was written with.

So, Is there a way to get this table using only one code to get it as written in the URL ?

e.g:

```
 Poem <- xpathSApply(Data,"//p[@class='poem']&//font[@class='poem']",xmlValue)
```

Comment: You could use [XPath operators](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_operators.asp) (you probably need `|`) or just use a wildcard for the tag, e.g. `"//*[@class='poem']"`.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks so much, i used the wildcard approach and it worked,
, could you make it as an answer ?the two approaches please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is actually about appropriate selectors to grab multiple tags with a class of "poem". There are a few options. A simple option is to use a wildcard character `*` for the tag name in the XPath selector:

```
Poem <- xpathSApply(Data,"//*[@class='poem']",xmlValue)
```

If you only want `p` and `font` tags of class `"poem"`, but not, say a `div` tag of the same class, you can use an `|` (or) operator to select multiple options. Translated to `rvest`, which I find a little easier to read (though the same selector works fine in `xpathSApply`, as well):

```
library(rvest)

Poem <- URL %>% read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//p[@class="poem"] | //font[@class="poem"]') %>% 
    html_text(trim = TRUE)
```

Another option if using `rvest` is to use CSS selectors instead of XPath ones. In CSS, class is specified by `.`, so all you need for a wildcard version is `".poem"`; to limit to only `p` or `font` tags, use `"p.poem, font.poem"`. [Here's a fun tutorial on CSS selectors, if you like.](http://flukeout.github.io/)

```
Poem <- URL %>% read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes(css = '.poem') %>% 
    html_text(trim = TRUE)

head(Poem, 15)    # I don't speak Arabic, so check that the results make sense
##  [1] "أقداح و أحلام"             "أنا لا أزال و في يدي قدحي" "ياليل أين تفرق الشرب"     
##  [4] "ما زلت أشربها و أشربها"    "حتى ترنح أفقك الرحب"       "الشرق عُفر بالضباب فما"    
##  [7] "يبدو فأين سناك يا غرب؟"    "ما للنجوم غرقن ، من سأم"   "في ضوئهن و كادت الشهب ؟"  
## [10] "أنا لا أزال و في يدي قدحي" "ياليل أين تفرق الشرب ؟"    "******"                   
## [13] "الحان بالشهوات مصطخب"      "حتى يكاد بهن ينهار"        "و كأن مصاحبيه من ضرج"
```